# Update Input Value while mapping React Native

Tags: react-native

I am creating `react-native mobile` app. I have an array with some values. I want to set array's value into input field. I have added value in the fields but i can't able to update these values. I have set my values in a qty variable like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    qty:[],
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
  var ids = [];
  this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index) => {
    dataImage['pro-name'] != undefined && (
      ids.push({'qty':dataImage['pro-qty']})    
    )
  })

  this.setState({qty:ids})
}

render() {
  return {
    this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index)=>(
      <View key={Index} style={productStyle.cartview}>
        {dataImage['pro-name'] && (
          <View style={productStyle.cartmain}>
            <Input value={this.state.qty[Index]['qty']} onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this)} style={{width:40,height:40,textAlign:'left'}} />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    ))
  }
}
```

Its showing values properly into the input field but i can't able to type anything into the field to update the values. what can i do for this

Comment: You do not have `handleChangeInput` function defined in your code.

Comment: handleChangeInput(stateName, text) {
        this.setState({
            [stateName]: text
        })
    }

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to move your input container into separate class, its better approach and each component will handle its own state. Its easy to handle and will result better in performance too.

```
components = []

render() {
  return this.props.data.map((item, index) => (
    <CustomComponent data={item} index={index} ref={(ref) => this.components[index] = ref} />
  ))
}
```

You can then get child (`CustomComponent`) value from its ref.

```
this.components[index].getValue()
this.components[index].setValue('Value');
```

You will need to create these functions (`getValue` & `setValue`) in CustomComponent class.

#### solution

Here is solution to your query. You need to install `lodash` or find other solution to make a new copy `qty`.

```
<Input onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChangeText(text, index)} />

handleChangeText = (text, index) => {
  const qty = _.cloneDeep(this.state.qty);
  qty[index] = {
    qty: text
  }
  this.setState({qty})
}
```

Comment: I also used this but not working, actually i want to update only values that are showing in the input field. my array insert all the values in the field properly but can't updated.

Comment: This is not a complete solution, its just a sample. You need to modify it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Input's value is set to `this.state.qty[Index]['qty']`. And to change it on text edit, you can do it like this. You do not need to bind the function, instead use an arrow function like this.

```
onChangeText={ (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ <your-input-value-state>:newValue })
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the value of each `Input` individually on `onChange` event.

Replace your with `Input` with this

```
<Input value={this.state.qty[Index]['qty']}
       onChange={this.handleChangeInput.bind(this, Index)}
       style={{width:40,height:40,textAlign:'left'}}
/>
```

and update the state accordingly with the `Index` when the `event` is called

```
handleChangeInput(index, value){
    let {qty} = this.state;
    let qty_update = qty.slice();
    qty_update[index]['qty']  = value;
    this.setState({qty: qty_update});
}
```